# Textmate RSpec Run Example fails

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

When I try to run an RSpec example from within Textmate.  I get "Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2 (you have 1.3.1). Please `gem update --system` and try again." I run gem update and I get nothing to update.  I think the RSpec bundle is running from the built in directories rather than /local/.  How do I change where the bundle looks?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

So far the only solution that works is to install the new rails bundle.  This has not proved to be a permanent fix as I had to remove and reinstall the bundle after a reboot.  It also seems to only work with the rails bundle as I just installed the compass and blueprint bundle just after the reboot.

Hopefully a smart person can id a permanent fix

Thanks!